# In what states does Sony A6300 support setPostviewImageSize?

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I'm calling `setPostviewImageSize` with size `Original` on the camera API of my Sony A6300. No matter what I do (ie. do startRec first, or change the order of this so it is after other calls), I always get the response `{"id":6,"error":[1,"Not Available Now"]}`.  When is it available, or does this camera not support Original?

Edit: I updated Smart Remote Control to latest version (4.2.0) and this did not help

Edit 2: I saw it work ONE time. So apparently this camera DOES support this command, but only in some state that I cannot understand...

Edit 3: must be the status of the camera. During init, even if I wait for IDLE status I still cannot setPostviewImageSize.

Here are my commands in the order i'm issuing them right after connecting. These are of course method names of my own code, should be pretty obvious which API calls these are...

checkSupportedMethodTypes -> getAvailableApiList -> setCameraFunctionToRemoteShooting -> startRecMode -> setShootModeToStill -> setPostviewSizeToOriginal

Edit 4: after further testing I can see that even though the camera reports IDLE, it clearly is lying -- after 4 seconds without any changes anywhere, it reports a whole new set of available APIs. So I am going to have to build some sort of sleep for this?!

Answer (score 0):

After testing the A6300 further, I needed to wait with setPostviewImageSize for at least 4 seconds even after the camera says it is IDLE and ready and doing nothing

Not cool, Sony...